# dart ffi how to copy Uint8List to Pointer<Uint8>?

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

I read a file `var list = await file.readAsBytes();` and want to copy it to clang `Pointer<Uint8> buf = malloc.allocate(list.length);`. I know I can do it `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) buf.elementAt(i).value = list[i];`. Is there anther method to do it just like clang `memcpy`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the code you have is what we support.

We would like to support giving access to the contents of `Uint8List` to native code in `leaf` FFI calls ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44589)), then the `memcpy` function can be used in native code to do the copying.

Alternatively, we could add support in `dart:ffi` itself for copying between `Pointer` and `TypedData` ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43968)).

As a workaround if you're blocked by the speed, you could use [`dart_api.c`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/runtime/include/dart_api.h) (in Dart standalone only, not Flutter):

```cpp
DART_EXPORT Dart_Handle Dart_TypedDataAcquireData(Dart_Handle object,
                                                  Dart_TypedData_Type* type,
                                                  void** data,
                                                  intptr_t* len);
```

You can make pass the `TypedData` through `dart:ffi` to native to get a `Dart_Handle` and then do a memcopy.